# Displaying Triple Nested Form Values (Rails 5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-loops, nested-forms

I'm having problems working out how to display the deepest values in a triple nested resource.  (`Roast`, `Country`, `Region`).

I'm able to display the first level ok with:

```
<% for countries in @roast.countries %>
   <br />
  <strong>Country:</strong>
  <%= countries.country_name %>
<% end %>
```

But I can't get the next level to display.

> undefined method 'regions' for #`<Country::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbaf8ad25b8>`

I've tried the following, but this doesn't work.

```
<% for regions in @roast.countries.regions %>
   <br />
  <strong>Country:</strong>
  <%= countries.regions.region_name %>
<% end %>
```

`@roast.country.regions` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one country and you need to fetch all regions for this country then loop looks like this

```
<% for region in @roast.countries.first.regions %>
    <br />
    <strong>Region:</strong>
    <%= region.region_name %>
<% end %>
```

Or if you need to show all regions for all countries then loop looks like this

I guess model relation looks like

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :countries
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :roast
    has_many :regions
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :country
end
```

Then

```
<% for country in @roast.countries %>
    <br />
    <strong>Country:</strong>
    <%= country.country_name %>

    <% for region in country.regions %>
        <br />
        <strong>Region:</strong>
        <%= region.region_name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Most preferrable is ruby `each` method instead of `loop` like below

```
<% @roast.countries.each do |country|  %>
    <br />
    <strong>Country:</strong>
    <%= country.country_name %>

    <% country.regions.each do |region|  %>
        <br />
        <strong>Region:</strong>
        <%= region.region_name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yep, that each method works perfectly @fool-dev. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, it should look something like:

```
<% @roast.countries.each do |country| %>
  <div class='country-container'>
    <div class='country title'>
      Country:
    </div>
    <div class='country-name'>
      <%= country.country_name %>
    </div>
    <div class='regions-container'>
      <div class='region title'>
        Regions:
      </div>
      <div class='regions'>
        <% country.regions.each do |region| %>
          <div class='region'>
            <%= region.name %>
          </div>
        <% end %>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

All those `divs` with `classes` will let you do your styling in `css` instead of having to do `<strong>`, etc. For instance, if you are using `sass`, you could do something like:

```
.country-container
  .title
    font-weight: bold
    font-size: 110%
    &.country 
      color: red 
    &.region
      color: blue
  .regions-container
    .region
      color: green
```

This:

```
<% for countries in @roast.countries %>
```

is not very ruby-esque. You should use `each` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for country in @roast.countries %>
  <br />
  <strong>Country:</strong>
  <%= country.country_name %>

  <br/>
  <p>Regions:</p>
  <% for region in country.regions %>
    <%= region.region_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You have for each country select its regions